# Python List Has Size, But Elements Cannot Be Accessed

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have constructed some code that culls data from a file, splits each line into three chunks, and outputs the three chunks as a list:

```
def n1gramSep(fileLine):
    output = []
    stringBuffer = ""

    for char in fileLine:
        if char not in "!\"$.%&\'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890":
            if stringBuffer != "":
                output.append(stringBuffer) 
            stringBuffer = ""
        else:
            stringBuffer += char     
    return output
```

And it works! However, in a later function, when I try to assign some the elements of the list to some variables, I keep getting IndexError: list index out of range.

But this is very odd - because when I ask for the program to print the content of the list, I clearly get the result I expect: example: `['9.99', 'dog', '5.25]` . Then, when I also check for the length of each list, I get the expected value of 3 as well.

Yet whenever I attempt
`nInfo.append(n1gramInfo[x])` where x is 0 , 1, or 2 it always fails.

I am absolutely stumped! Is there something I am misunderstanding?

Thanks.

Comment: unrelated: `output = filter(None, re.split(re.escape("!\"$.%&'")+"[a-z0-9]", fileLine))`

Comment: `print(repr(n1gramInfo), repr(x))` just before `nInfo.append`

Comment: J.F.Sebastian, when I add `print(repr(n1gramInfo))` just before the append, I get a healthy list! For example, taken from CMD: `['6.483171', 'bridegrooms', '0.7878781']`

Comment: and what is `print(repr(x))` in the same place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have one line in the file that is causing problems. There is often a blank line at the end for example

You can try somthing like this to isolate your problem

```
try:
    nInfo.append(n1gramInfo[x])
except IndexError:
    print(n1gramInfo, x)
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()  # optional, but a good time to learn the debugger
```

Comment: This seems to be the problem - thank you. I should make it a habit to "try" faulty statements more often. Thanks you very much.